Understanding the generalized "Birthday Problem" formula
While practicing frequently asked probability questions during interviews, I came across the classical "Birthday problem". While I understand some of the reasoning explained on wikipedia, there's part of the generalized formula I do not fully understand. And I would be very grateful to recieve some explanation,
First let's examine an classical example that is also explained at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem ;

How many people do we need in a project group to make the probability that two people have the same birthday more than 50%? Assume that there are exactly 365 days in a year.

I found it quite intuitive as is stated there that we first seek to find the probability that the number of people do not share the same birthday.

Which is; (365/365 * 364/365 * 363/365 ... and so on repeated for the amount of people in the project group)

However from here on, I get lost on how to find a generalized formula, except that I know that one minus this probability will give me the probability that there are at least two people who share the same birthday.
This is what is shown on wikipedia;

However, I don't fully understand this derivation, nor how we know that we find 23.
Finally it then concludes that;

Additionally solving it with permutations as is done here;

Seems pretty straightforward, however, how do we determine which k to use?
I look forward to your comments and anwsers.
Thank you in advance,
Kind regards, Julien

You could make an argument using things like sterling's approximations and actually come up with a formula to have found the value of $23$... but realistically, it is far easier to guess and check for values until having eventually come to the conclusion that numbers smaller than $23$ are too small and numbers larger than $23$ are too large, and so $23$ is the value you seek.  No, you didn't need to check every value, but I would probably have tried $10$ then $20$ then $30$, then $25$, then $22,23,24$ and finished there.

Makes sense, thank you! I just looked at the duplicate post that I didn't know existed before. Looks like Stirling's approach is the more algebraic way of doing things and the other the more simulation type of approach. Where we just plug in numbers till we get the desired probabilities.
